# How to get char from HTML character code?

Tags: javascript, special-characters, html-entities

How can I convert the HTML entities `&#8364; &#9658; &#9824;` to their actual characters `€ ► ♠` using JavaScript?

Comment: `String.fromCharCoode()`

Comment: And don't forget it only takes the number... i.e. String.fromCharCode(8364); // NOT String.fromCharCode("&#8364;");

Answer (score 11, accepted):

An example would be: `alert(String.fromCharCode(8364));`

Where 8364 is the number of the HTML entity.

To replace a full body of text automatically then you will need to use this regular expression replacement example:

```
"The price of milk is now &#8364;100000.".replace(/&#(\d{0,4});/g, function(fullStr, str) { return String.fromCharCode(str); });
```

The magic happens here:

`replace(/&#(\d{1,4});/g, function(fullStr, code) { return String.fromCharCode(code); });`

The first argument to replace, `/&#(\d{1,4});/g`, specifies 1 to 4 digits surrounded by &# and ; respectively. The second parameter, `function(fullStr, code) [...]` does the replacement, where `code` is the digits.

Comment: This only replaces the first occurrence. Is there a way to expand on this to match multiple occurrences of character codes in a string?

Comment: @darudude Sure, just add a `g` flag at the end of your regex to make it greedy: `'regex regex regex'.replace(/regex/g, 'bacon');` -> 'bacon bacon bacon'

Answer (score 3):

You could use the browser's built-in HTML parser via `innerHTML`, which will have the advantage of handling all HTML entities, not just numeric ones. Note that the following will not work if the string passed to the function contains HTML tags.

```
function convertEntities(html) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = html;
    return el.firstChild.data;
}

var html = "&#8364; &#9658; &#9824; &quot; &amp;";
var text = convertEntities(html); // € ► ♠ " &
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = "&#8364".fromCharCode();
```

Actually, scratch that, the `fromCharCode()` function is only available on the String object, so it would look like what **Will Morgan** said:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(8364)
```